# Stripe code is implemented in web-app, but Apple pay 'Double Click to Pay' button is not appearing

Tags: html, css, stripe-payments

[image]

Implemented the stripe's official code. In stripe account, Cards Payment method is enabled.
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#

```
 paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', function(ev) {
// Confirm the PaymentIntent without handling potential next actions (yet).
 stripe.confirmCardPayment(
 clientSecret,
 {payment_method: ev.paymentMethod.id},
   {handleActions: false}
 ).then(function(confirmResult) {
 if (confirmResult.error) {
  // Report to the browser that the payment failed, prompting it to
  // re-show the payment interface, or show an error message and close
  // the payment interface.
  ev.complete('fail');
  } else {
  // Report to the browser that the confirmation was successful, prompting
  // it to close the browser payment method collection interface.
  ev.complete('success');
  // Check if the PaymentIntent requires any actions and if so let Stripe.js
  // handle the flow. If using an API version older than "2019-02-11"
  // instead check for: `paymentIntent.status === "requires_source_action"`.
  if (confirmResult.paymentIntent.status === "requires_action") {
    // Let Stripe.js handle the rest of the payment flow.
    stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // The payment failed -- ask your customer for a new payment method.
      } else {
        // The payment has succeeded.
      }
    });
   } else {
    // The payment has succeeded.
  }
  }
  });
});
```

Current iOS version is 15.7. Apple Pay payment is working smoothly on other iPhone devices, but on some devices, 'Double Click to Pay' button is not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `requestPayerName` set to `true` when [creating a Payment Request](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_request/create#stripe_payment_request-options-requestPayerName) then a valid billing address is required to complete payment. This would explain why you're seeing it working for some devices and not others - the devices that it's working for have valid billing addresses for their cards, but the device from the screenshot does not. You need to update your Wallet settings to add a valid billing address for this card or set `requestPayerName: false` so that it's no longer required.